# Recursing through nested collections of objects always terminates at first leaf node

Tags: javascript, recursion

I've got a collection of directory-like objects, each of which has as a property an array of the same kind of object. This structure begins with a single root and the implementation has no theoretical constraints on length.

Here's the collection of objects:

```
var filesystemObjects = [
    {
        path: '/',
        children: 
        [
            {
                path: '/users',
                children: 
                [           
                    {
                        path: '/users/firstuser',
                        children: 
                        [                   
                            {
                                path: '/users/firstuser/documents',
                                children: 
                                [

                                ]
                            },
                        ]
                    },              
                    {
                        path: '/users/seconduser',
                        children: 
                        [
                            {
                                path: '/users/seconduser/documents',
                                children: 
                                [

                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                path: '/programFiles',
                children: 
                [

                ]
            },      
            {
                path: '/kurfleOS',
                children: 
                [
                    {
                        path: '/kurfleOS/passwd',
                        children:
                        [

                        ]
                    },
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
];
```

This seems like it should be fairly trivial, albeit not especially efficient, to visit every node (and, by extension, return the object that matches a path query string). The code does not fail to compile because of semicolons or brackets.

Here's the test method I'm using:

```
function directoryRecurse(dir) {
    console.log(dir);
    for (ii = 0; ii < dir.children.length; ii++) {
        directoryRecurse(dir.children[ii]);
    }
}
```

But every time, the method searches (and prints) only until it reaches the first leaf node (`/users/firstuser/documents`, in this case), the output ceases entirely. There are no errors at all, and the method works as expected up to that point. I'm really not sure why, particularly because the same algorithm, superficially modified, works exactly as expected for arrays containing arrays containing etc. What exactly am I missing as far as allowing this method to actually traverse the entirety of the root?

Comment: How is your function called?

Comment: @Ja͢ck In the test case, with directoryRecurse(filesystemObjects[0]).

Comment: @nem When you say "works fine," what exactly do you mean? On both Chrome and Firefox, I get only four results, terminating at `/users/firstuser/documents`. And being able to see the whole content isn't the issue - I need to be able to reach the node objects, not just print a string that happens to contain the stringified representation of it somewhere within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a global variable in your recursive function:

```
function directoryRecurse(dir) {
    console.log(dir);
    for (ii = 0; ii < dir.children.length; ii++) {
//       ^^
        directoryRecurse(dir.children[ii]);
    }
}
```

You need to declare the variable as local so that each recursive step doesn't interfere with each other:

```
for (var ii = 0; ii < dir.children.length; ii++) {
//   ^^^
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. I'm somewhat new to javascript, and didn't realize there was a semantic difference between `var ii` and `ii`. (I knew this was a dumb enough question to make an alt account)

Answer (score -2):

```
path: '/users/seconduser',
                    children: 
                    [
                        {,// try this and for ascending lines as well
//Why did you not put a comma here wouldn't this end
//your execution. You have commas on all other lines you say execute
```

.

Comment: Put a comma where? (This is not a compile-time error. There are no errors at all.)

Comment: Send me a file of your full code, if its not a compiler error it must be internal.

Comment: I've added the full collection of objects. That, and the method I've pasted in its full, are the entirety of the relevant code.